# React Native - making if inside dispatch to decide to send variable / not

Tags: javascript, react-native, api

I am currently trying to use an API. From what I tested in postman, the server got internal error (status: 500) if I send voucher_id with data that is not recognized (it only accept 1  & 2, the rest is not acceptable). If I remove voucher_id in the postman, the code works properly (from what I see, it has no problem if no voucher_id. The API gives different response compared to when it has voucher_id). So I want to make if to check whether I can remove voucher_id or not.

```
<TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
        dispatch(
          PaymentAssesment({
            project_id: params.id,
            name: params.name,
            voucher_id: disc ? disc.id : '',
          }),
        );
      }}>
      <Text style={styles.itemButton}>Lanjutkan</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

This is the code I got and I wonder how to change this to make if to either include voucher_id or just remove it

Comment: disc ? disc.id : undefined

Comment: oh right it did work. If you want to put it to answer then go ahead :)